ライフタイム注釈に関して
やってみてうまくいったこと
nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-gnuを用いて、Iterableというトレイトを実装しようとしました。
当該トレイトは以下のとおりです。
pub trait Iterable {
    type Iter: Iterator;
    fn iter(&self) -> Self::Iter;
}

このトレイトが問題ないのか確かめるため、&[T]を対象とした実装を以下のように行いました。
pub struct SliceIterable<'a, T>(&'a [T]);

impl<'a, T: 'a> Iterable for crate::iterable::SliceIterable<'a, T> {
    type Iter = Iter<'a, T>;
    fn iter(&self) -> Self::Iter {
        self.0.iter()
    }
}

うまくいかなかったこと
ここまでは問題なかったのですが、以下のように、タプルの中身を＆mut ［T］としたところ、
以下のようなコンパイルエラーが発生しました。
pub struct MutSliceIterable<'a, T>(&'a mut [T]);

impl<'a, T: 'a> Iterable for MutSliceIterable<'a, T> {
    type Iter = Iter<'a, T>;

    fn iter(&self) -> Self::Iter {
        self.0.iter()
    }
}

発生したコンパイルエラーは以下になります
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src\iterable.rs:25:3
   |
21 | impl<'a, T: 'a> Iterable for MutSliceIterable<'a, T> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
24 |     fn iter(&self) -> Self::Iter {
   |             - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
25 |         self.0.iter()
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ method was supposed to return data with lifetime `'a` but it is returning data with lifetime `'1`

具体的な質問の内容
概略、ライフタイムの省略で推論されたライフタイムとSeld::Iterの'aがミスマッチを起こしているという意味は理解したのですが、なぜmut無しの場合は、コンパイルが問題なく通せて、mutを付けるとこのようなコンパイルエラーが発生しているのか理解できませんでした。
また、現状に於いて僕が当該事象の解釈として、immutableの実装（コンパイルが成功した事例）では
SliceIterableのコンテンツが、そもそも&'a ［T］となっており、self.0の段階で、＆'a ［T］の参照を対象としており、その参照に対してiterメソッドを実行しているので結果的に、返却値がslice::Iter<'a,T>'と推論されたのではないか
と解釈しました。この解釈に基づけばMutSliceIterableの内容が例えmutableになっても同様の解釈が成立すると考えたのですが、現実は先の通りコンパイルエラーとなっております。
どちらもコンパイルエラーが発生する、またはどちらもコンパイルが通せるということであれば疑問はなかったのですが、mutの有無で可否が変化してしまったことがどうしても理解できません。
この件に関して何か知見をお持ちの方は、何卒ご教授いただきますようよろしくお願い申し上げます。
追記
IteratorのNextが参照を返すことを必須としたときどうなるのか追加的に思慮する過程で以下のような実装を思いつき実行してみました。
use std::slice::Iter;

pub trait ReferenceIterator<'a, T: 'a>: Iterator<Item=&'a T> {}

impl<'a, T: 'a> ReferenceIterator<'a, T> for Iter<'a, T> {}

pub trait Iterable {
    type Item;

    fn iter(&self) -> impl ReferenceIterator<'_, Self::Item>;
}


pub struct SliceIterable<'a, T: 'a>(&'a [T]);

impl<'a, T: 'a> Iterable for SliceIterable<'a, T> {
    type Item = T;

    fn iter(&self) -> impl ReferenceIterator<'_, Self::Item> {
        self.0.iter()
    }
}

pub struct MutSliceIterable<'a, T: 'a>(&'a mut [T]);

impl<'a, T: 'a> Iterable for MutSliceIterable<'a, T> {
    type Item = T;

    fn iter(&self) -> impl ReferenceIterator<'_, Self::Item> {
        self.0.iter()
    }
}

この事例の場合、ライフタイム省略をうまく使うコトが出来るので、当該の問題は発生しないようです。

どうにか理解できないかとこねくり回していたところ、自分なりに解釈が出来たのでまとめておきます。
もし、当該解釈に齟齬が有る場合はご指摘ください。
use std::slice::Iter as SliceIter;

pub trait Iterable {
    type Iter: Iterator;
    fn iter(&self) -> Self::Iter;
}
pub struct SliceIterable<'a, T>(&'a [T]);

impl<'a, T: 'a> Iterable for SliceIterable<'a, T> {
    type Iter = SliceIter<'a, T>;
    fn iter(&self) -> Self::Iter {
        //Immutableなので、参照を複製可能。従ってreferenceは＆'a ［T］となる。
        let reference: &[T] = self.0;

        //従ってIter<'a,T>の'aを満たすのでコンパイル可能
        reference.iter()
    }
}

pub struct MutSliceIterable<'a, T>(&'a mut [T]);

impl<'a, T: 'a> Iterable for MutSliceIterable<'a, T> {
    type Iter = SliceIter<'a, T>;

    fn iter(&self) -> Self::Iter {
        //&mut [T]は1つしか作成出来ない。従って参照の参照を取る必要がある。
        //この時点でこの参照の参照は'_とInferされる。
        let refref: &&mut [T] = &self.0;

        //なので、そこからImmutableな参照をこさえても
        //'_とInferされ続ける
        let refer = refref as &[T];

        //従ってslide::Iter<'_,T>が返却値となってしまい、Iter<'a,T>とミスマッチが発生する
        refer.iter()
    }
}

self.0をより深く観察するために、一度変数に束縛してみたところ、SliceIterable のほうは、問題なくコンパイルが可能であり、質問にあった僕の解釈で問題ないことが理解できました。
一方、MutSliceIterableの場合、SliceIterableと同様の実装を行おうとした場合、
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `self` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src\iterable.rs:22:14
   |
22 |         let reference = self.0;
   |                    ^^^^^^ move occurs because `self.0` has type `&mut [T]`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |
help: consider borrowing here
   |
22 |         let reference = &self.0;
   |                    +

このようなコンパイルエラーが発生します。これはmut [T]は当然Copyトレイトを実装していないので、Moveが発生しますがそんなことは出来ないよと言うことになります。
結果的に、上記のように参照の参照を取得して、そこからMutableな参照を取得することになると考えられるので、最終的なiterメソッドによって作成された、slice::Iter は、Iter<'_,T>となり、Iterで要請している'Iter<'a,T>'を満たさなくなるので、コンパイルエラーが発生したものと考察しました。
